# String replace returns unterminated character

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to escape a string `df['col'].str.replace('][', ']|[')` 
Anywhere where there are two closing and opening square bracket next to each other
There should be a '|' placed between them. My code returns the below error. I am pretty sure I do not
need escape characters here.

```
 error: unterminated character set at position 1
```

Comment: Try using `regex=False` parameter. According to the doc, default is to treat input as regex so you need to escape `[`. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: _pretty sure_ wasn't enough in that case ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9][10,11,12]']})
df['A'] = df['A'].str.replace('\]\[', ']|[')
print(df)
```